# Convert CSV with nested JSON values to Pandas

Tags: json, pandas, amazon-web-services, csv

I am working with a CSV file that has some data saved in a nested JSON format.

Example dataset (When I load the CSV file into Pandas):
-I need to convert the values in the data (M) category into separate columns. Currently they are saved as lists

```
    deviceId (S)    timestamp (S)   data (M)
0   3377    1523128290722   { "deviceId" : { "N" : "3377" }, "device...
1   736 1523128294737   { "deviceId" : { "N" : "736" }, "deviceI...
2   4963    1523128290731   { "deviceId" : { "N" : "4963" }, "device...
```

The data in column data (M) is a nested list

```
user_dict = df['data (M)']

[In] type([user_dict]) is list
[Out] True
```

Here are some code examples I have tried:

```
user_dict = df['data (M)']


pd.DataFrame.from_dict({(i,j): user_dict[i][j] 
                           for i in user_dict.keys() 
                           for j in user_dict[i].keys()},
                       orient='index')


AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

-

```
user_dict = df['data (M)']
df2 = pd.DataFrame(user_dict[1:],columns=data[0])


TypeError: Index(...) must be called with a collection of some kind, '{' was passed
```

Ultimately I want a Pandas DataFrame that looks like this:

```
deviceId (S)    timestamp (S)   temperature (N)                  (N) Humidity (N)
0   3377    1523128290722   { "Temperature" : { "N" : "24.2424" }, { "Humdity" : { "N" : "24.2424" }
1   736 1523128294737   { "Temperature" : { "N" : "24.466" }, { "Humdity" : { "N" : "24.2424" }
2   4963    1523128290731   { "Temperature" : { "N" : "26.4534" }, { "Humdity" : { "N" : "24.2424" }
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of input json.

Comment: Try executing 'type(user_dict[0]) is str'.  Using brackets [ object ]  is the same as calling list( object).  'type([1234]) is list' will evaluate to True.  Looks like data (M) will need to be converted before the second block will work.

Comment: Example JSON:

{"timestamp":{"s":"1523128290722"},"data":{"m":{"humidity":{"n":"76"},"deviceIP":{"s":"183.254.78.17"},"deviceId":{"n":"3377"},"temperature":{"n":"21"}}},"deviceId":{"s":"3377"}}
{"timestamp":{"s":"1523128294737"},"data":{"m":{"humidity":{"n":"23"},"deviceIP":{"s":"36.194.163.37"},"deviceId":{"n":"736"},"temperature":{"n":"110"}}},"deviceId":{"s":"736"}}
{"timestamp":{"s":"1523128290731"},"data":{"m":{"humidity":{"n":"18"},"deviceIP":{"s":"23.47.105.88"},"deviceId":

Comment: This is the Dynamodb JSON format from AWS. Hence why it is weird looking.